# 'Implementation 'com.android.support: appcompat-v7:27.1.1' issue

Tags: java, android

Underlining in red in Android studio? Showing it is to do with the version of it clashing with another although, I can not see another. Has anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: please explain bit more about your question. thanks

Comment: use `27.1.0` some of the dependencies might not have been upgraded... may b `recyclerView` found in `support:27.1.1`

Comment: can you post dependencies from your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

1 - download this project and open it in android studio and update what it needs here link : https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix

2 - in your project app ( build.gradle ) add this :

dependencies{

.....

implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

}

3 - Sync Project...